# Найти сумму элементов матрицы ниже побочной диагонали - C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Помогите задать условие "ниже побочной диагонали".

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int M;
    int N;
    int i, j;
    double** matrix;
    cout << endl << "M = " ;
    cin >> M;
    cout << endl  << "N = " ;
    cin >> N;

    matrix = new double*[M];
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        matrix[i] = new double[N];

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) // ввод 
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            cout << "Inter element " << "[" << i << "][" << j << "]  ";
            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }



    cout << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N ; j++) {

        }
    }
    cout << endl << sum << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Просто нужно цикл j не от 0 а от `N - i` начинать и тогда все `matrix[i][j]` будут те что нужны. Только это если матрица квадратная, для неквадратной не понятно что такое диагональ.

Comment: Ниже диагонали у вас - элементы с индексами строки, на 1 меньше индексов на диагонали (т.е. такая "параллельная линия", или **все** элементы, находящиеся ниже диагонали (треугольник или трапеция из элементов)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что такое побочная диагональ - это диагональ, которая идет сверху-права на низ-лево. Нужная "диагональ ниже" - это просто плюс единица по высоте. Но есть одна проблема - у не квадратной матрицы нужно точно определить, что называть диагональю.

Итак, если бы это была квадратная матрица размером size x size, и нумерация с нуля, то побочная диагональ это (схематически)

```
s=0;
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
  s+=m[size-i][i-1]
}
```

А с диагональню ниже, будет так (заметье, что размер этой диагонали на 1 меньше)

```
s=0;
for (int i = 1; i <= size-1; i++) {
  s+=m[size-i][i]
}
```

Comment: на первой же итерации программа упадёт, почему у вас не `m[size-i-1]` ? индексация же с нуля ...

Comment: да, рука по привычке нули написала.

Comment: в этом случае тоже упадёт - при `i = size` элемент `m[size-i][i]` выйдет за рамки массива

Comment: Порывшись в Интернете, обнаружил, что обычно побочная диагональ для неквадратных - выходящая из нижнего левого угла. Но у вас - суммируются только элементы, лежащие непосредственно рядом, а нужно суммировать, как я понимаю, эдакий треугольник (или трапецию)?

Comment: а вот я не знаю, может там все слишком хитрее. Надо уточнять.

Answer (score 0):

Элементы ниже побочной диагонали в матрице с `M` строками и `N` столбцами - те `a[i][j]`, для которых `i+j > M-1`.

Можно просто перебором по всем элементам и отсеивать ненужные, а можно - по каждой строке `i` от `M-i`-го элемента до `N-1`-го...